# Having Problems Fetching from google sheets script

Tags: reactjs, google-sheets

Im trying to extract data from a google sheets, and im having trouble even fetching it. Im trying to make a form, users data will input it into a google sheet, and i want to pull out certain data, this case being the email and id, so i can compare it to the current form data and determine if its a duplicate to reject it, but i cant fetch it. I can write into it but take out that data no.
My code:

```
const scriptURL = 'your script here';
const [existingFormData, setExistingFormData] = useState([]); // State for existing form data from the Google Spreadsheet

  // Fetch existing data from the Google Spreadsheet on component mount
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        // Fetch the data from your Google Apps Script
        console.log('Fetching data from the Google Spreadsheet...');
        const response = await fetch(scriptURL);
        console.log('Response:', response);

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
        if (!contentType || !contentType.includes('application/json')) {
          throw new TypeError('Oops, we haven\'t got JSON!');
        }

        // Parse the JSON data from the response
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log('Data:', data);
        
        // Set the existing form data in your state
        setExistingFormData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching existing data:', error);
      }
    };

    // Call the fetchData function when the component mounts
    fetchData();
  }, []); // The empty dependency array ensures that this runs only once after the component mounts
```

Google Sheets Script:

```
const sheetName = 'BHD';
const scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success!')
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function initialSetup() {
  const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId());
}

function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log('doPost function is running.');
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(10000);

  try {
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'));
    const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);

    const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    Logger.log(data);

    // Initialize arrays to store studentEmail and studentID
    const studentEmailArray = [];
    const studentIDArray = [];

    // Loop through the 2D list
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      // Get the student email and ID from each row
      const studentEmail = data[i][2]; // Targeting the third item in each list (index 2)
      const studentID = String(data[i][3]); // Converts ID from scientific notation to string
      
      // Log the values for verification
      Logger.log(studentEmail);
      Logger.log(studentID);

      // Store the values in arrays
      studentEmailArray.push(studentEmail);
      studentIDArray.push(studentID);
    }

    // Return an object with the arrays
    return createTextOutputWithCors(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'studentEmailArray': studentEmailArray, 'studentIDArray': studentIDArray }));

  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Error in opening spreadsheet:', error.message);
    return createTextOutputWithCors({ 'result': 'error', 'error': error.message });
  } finally {
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function createTextOutputWithCors(data) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(data).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

I tried to get a new script exc url to see if that changed anything but no.

Comment: Can I ask you about the setting of your Web Apps? What are the values of `Execute as:` and `Who has access to the app:`? And, in your situation, the account of your Web Apps is in Google workspace? And, what is your current error message? By the way, in your showing script, it seems that you request your Web Apps with GET method. But, `doGet` returns `HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success!')`. Is this your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your situation.

Comment: I deployed it as a web app, me for execute as, anyone has access to my script, the error i get from the console is TypeError: Failed to fetch, and i don't need the doGet function, it was just me testing.